# Error using GDI+ DrawArc makes no sense "ArgumentException was unhandled by user code"

Tags: c#, gdi+, indexer

See picture for the code generating the error. I've tried re-ordering things and it always happens on the second call to `DrawArc`. I simply copy pasted the line

```
g.DrawArc(SystemPens.ButtonFace, outerCircle[-1], 115, 220);
```

twice in a row to illustrate the error wasn't occurring because of a typo or miscalculation.
It runs fine the first time, errors the second.[image: Code generating error and error message]

Code that calls `ReLayout()`:

```
    public ButtonFan()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < buttonLabels.Count(); i++)
        {
            buttonLabels[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.buttonLabels[i].Name = "label"+i.ToString();
            this.buttonLabels[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 23);
            this.buttonLabels[i].TabIndex = i;
            this.buttonLabels[i].Text = "label"+i.ToString();
        }
        ReLayout();
    }
```

Comment: What calls ReLayout? Is it by chance being called from a thread?

Comment: @Pete `ReLayout()` is called last thing in the form constructor.

Comment: You may want to call it from OnLoad() or the Form.Load event instead of the constructor. And to confirm, you're calling it directly, not via some sort of threading? That is, this code is executing on the main thread and not a worker thread, correct?

Comment: Also, can you post the exception details and call stack. Is there an inner exception?

Comment: it seems like the problem is with outerCircle[-1] - what does that evaluate to?

Comment: @MikyDinescu He has the code for the indexer posted. See the image.

Comment: What is this line suppose to do: `int growBy = shrinkTo - maxLegal;`?  It seems to make a negative sized rectangle.

Comment: I know. But it really looks like outerCircle[-1] evaluates to an invalid parameter for DrawArc!

Comment: Actually, you're right @LarsTech

Comment: @AppFzx - have you tried stepping through with the debugger? The problem most likely stems from your "clever" implementation of InnerRectangle and the way you are re-using the same object "outerCircle" (which is actually a rectangle ;))

Comment: Ok, so LarsTech was right. I'm attempting to shrink the rectangle past 0 width. Why then does it not error until the second time I pass invalid arguments?

Comment: To whoever -1'd this and didn't comment, explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the error was generated in the FIRST

```
g.DrawArc(SystemPens.ButtonFace, outerCircle[-1], 115, 220);
```

statement. Still not sure why it didn't complain until the next one but the way I discovered it was by adding a line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Finished first arc");
```

after the first arc draw. The error then popped up on the `Console.WriteLine`.
Of course `Console.WriteLine` wasn't erroring so that means it had to have rolled over from the previous statement which attempted to resize a rectangle to negative size and draw an arc in it.

Changing the `[-1]` to `[150]` solved the problem.